# Magento and Subdomains

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to have magento in a subdomain but have the main index.php in the main domain.

So I have www.mysite.com and users come to this url when they click on a menu link eg shoes they are taken to store.mysite.com

Answer (score 1):

Answer of your first question: Yes, it's possible, you need to edit index.php & find the line

> define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

change getcwd() to your sub-domain path

---

if you want to create a sub-domain store using magento following link could help you: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

Answer (score 0):

You may put your site subdomain/directory & main domain may use as landing page.
add below code topmost of header.phtml

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])){
    setcookie("firsttime", "no" );// EXPIRE     $getMegBaseUrl=Mage::getBaseUrl();
    header('Location: '.'http://www.landing.com/index.php');
    exit(); }
```

for landing page another directory/folder

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])){
    setcookie("firsttime", "no" );// EXPIRE 
    $getMegBaseUrl=Mage::getBaseUrl();
    header('Location: '.$getMegBaseUrl.'landing/index.php');
    exit();
}
```